# Google Cloud Platform: Verify Application (OAuth)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

On Google Cloud Platform I created a project and OAuth 2.0 Client IDs. Everything works fine (register/login with Google Account) but I have a concern with the following screen at "OAuth consent screen"

[image]

It says that it needs verification, and that I should prepare my app to submit such a request. Everything is okay but when I click on "prepare your app" (from the picture above) it gives me the following screen

[image]

Would you please be so kind and let me know what are my next steps to verify my app and how can I do that?

Comment: There is a document stating how you should configure the OAuth for your project over [here](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849?hl=en), have you taken a look at it?

Comment: Hey @rsalinas, yes, I have taken a look at it. Somehow I can't figure it out.